# Algorithm for enumerating over all possible pairs, by size (with some added conditions)?

Tags: turing-machines, enumeration

Is there a way to enumerate, by size (the size of a pair is ||+|| but if the enumerator represents them in some different way than simply concatenating them (like via some different encoding) then we are just talking about the size || of the string  in the enumeration that encodes the pair (,)), from biggest to smallest, all pairs $(x,y)$ from two enumerable, countably-infinte sets, $X$ and $Y$, of words, in such a way that there is one element (in the enumeration) of each size (even above some min size: $|x|min + |y|min$ ($|x|min$ being the shortest string in $X$ and $|y|min$  being the shortest string in $Y$) would be fine), with the added condition: the enumerator needs to represent/ encode the pairs it enumerates in such a way that it doesn't "mangle" the pairs. To define mangle: we need to be able to extract (read) both the $x$ and $y$ encoded/represented in any string $s$ in the enumeration in poly time*.

**by poly time I mean measured in length of string in the enumeration (so if $|s|$ = $l$, for some $s$ in the enumeration, I would need to be able to recover $x$ and $y$ in fewer than $l^k$ steps.*

Just to reiterate, whatever encoding the enumerator uses to generate its representations of the pairs $(x,y)$...one needs to be able to decode any string $s$ in the enumeration back into the $(x,y)$ in $|s|^k$ time. PLUS there has to be at least one string of each length (again, above some min length would be fine) representing some valid pair. So, given a natural number $b$ (maybe above some smallest number $m$), there is an element of the enumeration $s$ such that $|s|=b$ and we can decode that string of length $b$ back into ($x,y$) in less than $b^k$ time (*and just as an aside, I think this also means $|x,y|<b^k$).*

Comment: Please ask only one question per post.  What is the "size" of a pair?  What is $|x|min$?

Comment: @D.W. |x|min is the shortest string in X and |y| min is the shortest string in Y. edited the question so that its one question.

Comment: @D.W. the size of a pair is |x| + |y| but if the enumerator represents them in some different way than simply concatenating them (like via some encoding) then we are just talking about the size |s| of the string s in the enumeration that encodes the pair (x,y)

Comment: Please don't answer in the comments.  Instead, edit the question so that is clear from the question and so that people don't need to ask and don't need to read the comments.

Comment: @D.W. ok did just that!