# Decide if a string is a member of a language that represents $P$?

Tags: polynomial-time, semi-decidability, enumeration

For some enumeration of the complexity class P (such as this as an example: [How does an enumerator for machines for languages work?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/126615/how-does-an-enumerator-for-machines-for-languages-work/126621?noredirect=1#comment266467_126621)), for each string  in the enumeration, does there exist some other string (certificate)  that allows you to verify  is a member of the enumeration in poly time? I believe that it might be possible in poly time because all we have to do is check if a string fits some certain format (format of the encoding)?

A decision problem $P$ is poly time verifiable iff there is an algorithm  called verifier such that if $P(w)=$ then there is a string $c$ s.t. $(w,c)=$, if $P(w)=$ then for all strings $c$, $(w,c)=$ and V runs in $O(w^{k})$ for some constant $k$ for all inputs $w$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can force the enumeration to be only on machines with a very strict format: a hard-coded poly time "clock" at the start, and after that the rest of the TM.

This will allow you to check in poly time (not even requiring a verifier) whether a given string $p$ is a part of the enumeration

Comment: So, this means that some languages representing P (encoding all languages in P) are in P. cool. I want to accept but how can i know if this is true? seems reasonable!

Comment: In fact, I think this reasoning should work for any deterministic complexity class you want to enumerate on, and the algorithm that checks whether the string is a part of the enumeration will still be poly time

Comment: what is the reasoning (you are saying specify larger and larger clocks at the start for each larger complexity class)? i believe the main problem is only poly time verifiable not poly time solvable because, if it were, i think you can derive a contradiction.

Comment: For a specific enumeration we define it can be done in the exact same way: add a counter to the start of every turing machine

Comment: Do you think you can you efficiently simulate the machines in the enumeration on any input?